# Browser Add-ons to learn German

Tags: learning, software

I am an active learner of German. I remember to have installed a browser Add-on on my old computer which helped me to learn the gender of German words by colorizing them in the browser using different colors. I tried to find it again and browsed through the page of FireFox and Chrome Add-ons but found nothing.

It would be also nice to get some information about other useful browser Add-ons for learning German language.

---

Ich lerne Deutsch seit geraumer Zeit und hatte auf meinem alten Rechner ein Browser-Add-on, das mir geholfen hat, das Geschlecht der deutschen Substantiven zu (er)lernen. Das Addon hat unter anderem alle Substantive auf einer Webseite abhängig von ihrem Geschlecht farblich markiert. Das Farbschema war auch flexibel einstellbar.

Ich habe jetzt versucht, das Addon wiederzufinden, leider ohne Erfolg. Kennt jemand so ein Addon?

Gerne würde ich auch über andere nützliche Addons zum Erlernen der deutschen Sprache erfahren, die man gesehen bzw. selber erprobt hat.

Comment: [geraumer](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/geraum) - [geräumt](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/raeumen)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Da keiner bisher meine Frage richtig beantworten konnte, erzähle ich über die Erweiterungen, die ich selber verwende, um mein Deutsch zu verbessern:

1. [Artikel Trainer](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/der-artikeltrainer/): Alle Artikeln im Text werden durch Dropdowns erstellt und man muss die richtigen Artikeln erraten.
   [image: Artikel Trainer Picture]
2. (endlich gefundene) [FireLang](https://sites.google.com/site/firelangsite/): hat viele Funktionen, inkluzive die farbliche Markierung von deutschen Substantiven nach Geschlecht, Artikel-Trainer für Englisch und Deutsch etc.
   [image]

Answer (score 3):

### [Bubble Translate](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jlhlebbhengjlhmcjebbkambaekglhkf)

Eine  Google Chrome Erweiterung, die Text übersetzt, den man hervorgehoben hat:

[image]

Ich finde sie echt nützlich für rasche Übersetzungen kleinerer Textpassagen und für Redewendungen. Ich glaube, dass sie Google Translate nutzt, das kürzlich ziemlich gut (besser) wurde, da EU Dokumente mit vielen Übersetzungen eingepflegt wurden.

Comment: "Spot"-Übersetzungen ist mir auch nicht geläufig, was bedeutet es genau?

Comment: @bernd_k Genau? Hmm. Eine Spot-Übersetzung ist vielleicht wie eine Stichprobe: man übersetz nicht den ganzen Abschnitt, nur ein Wort oder einen Satz.

Comment: Ach so. Ich wusste nicht, dass Leute die Antworten bearbeiten könnten. Klasse!

Comment: Es stört ein wenig, dass der Screenshot keine Übersetzung zeigt.

Answer (score 0):

Für Google Chrome gibt es auch einen Addon, der "Google Dictionary" heißt.
Ich habe Bubble Translate benutzt, aber so weit ich mich erinnern kann, musste man dort auch eine taste drucken. Auch, glaube ich dass Bubble Translate funktioniert nicht mehr, aber ich habe dass seit lange nicht überprüft.

Google Dictionary kann ohne Tastatur benutzt werden.

Hier ist das Link:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-dictionary-by-goog/mgijmajocgfcbeboacabfgobmjgjcoja?hl=en